# Include HTML, JavaScript, and CSS files in Visual Studio's Code Metrics Analysis

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-metrics

I would like to include HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files within the analysis of Code Metrics to get the number of lines for these files within my solution.

Is this possible?

Thank you.